# JSP mysql connections not closing, however in Java class it does

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am developing a web application using Java, JSP, MySQL. I cannot get the MySQL connections to close in the JSP, yet it works in a Java class. I have the following code:

A. First I have a class to get the ResultSet when running a get query as follows:

```
public static ResultSet get(String query) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL + DB_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return rs;
}
```

B. I have a java class using the above to return the MySQL results in objects as follows:

```
public static <E> E getByFromOtherRS(E element, List<String> columns, String tableName, String whereColumn, String whereValue, Method getFromRS) {
    try {
        String query = "Select * from " + tableName + " where " + whereColumn + "='" + whereValue + "';";
        ResultSet rs = SQLAccessor.get(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            try {
                element = (E) getFromRS.invoke(element, rs);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    } finally {
        try {
            SQLAccessor.getConnection().close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return element;
}
```

C. I then use the above in the below class. When I run the main method I get the result as expected. Also, when I do

> show status like '%onn%'

in the MySQL shell the number of Threads_connected are the same as before running the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(getUserByUsername()));
}

public static User getUserByUsername() {
    User user = Accessor.getByFromOtherRS(new User(), Accessor.getColumns("user"), "user", "username", "linda", Accessor.getFromRSMethod(UserAccessor.class));
    return user;
}
```

D. The problem is with the JSP. I have the below code in the JSP. I get the user email correctly, but the problem is with the MySQL - when I run the same command as above the number of Threads_connected are now 17 more.

```
    <%

    User user = DatabaseAccessor.getUserByUsername();
    System.out.println(user.getEmail());
%>
```

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your current code is incomplete (and hard to follow). You may also want to consider learning more modern techniques, because using code fragments in JSP went out of style more than a decade ago.

Comment: My advise is to throw away all the code and restart. Not using a connection pool will give you performance issues. But the worst thing is having one static Connection attribute that is not thread safe; imagine what could be happen if two threads call the get method before one of them call SQLAccessor.getConnection().close().

Comment: Certainly, `catch (SQLException ex) { //empty  }` is not a good approach to spot runtime errors... -.-

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the full code...

Given the code snippet, it will be better if you issue 'close' to the connection in a finally block to ensure it gets closed.

```
finally {
    if (connection!=null) { connection.close();}
}
```